# ASP.NET MVC 3 Reroute to other controller and action & Restful API versioning

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, rest, asp.net-web-api

**My original problem** is I am looking what is the best practise to do **versioning in Restful API**. Not much people talk about this, dont have a good answer or I can't found exactly the solution at this moment.

(1) At first I am thinking to use `Tag` or `Branch` for each version http://domain.com/API/{version}. So if new API released, I `Tag` it, export and publish into the respective URL but seems hard to mix the different revision of source in one web application.

(2) Then I am thinking to use this way, one controller for one version:
(Just like this question [Versioning of REST API Built With ASP.NET MVC 3 - Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634463/building-rest-api-with-asp-net-mvc-3))

`http://domain.com/API/1.0/{AnAction} => will go to APIV1Controller.{AnAction}`

`http://domain.com/API/2.0/{AnAction} => will go to APIV2Controller.{AnAction}`

but it need to write a route for each version.

(3) Third way I get the idea from PayPal API which is the version is not in the URL but in the POST parameter. So the URL fixed to `http://domain.com/API/` but user must specify the `Version` parameter to have `"1.0"` or `"2.0"`.

The solution for this: The (2) is ok for me, and currently I use this way but I want to mixed the (2) and (3) so I have a APIController which only have one Index action to check this `Version` parameter and transfer the request to the respective controller and action either APIV1Controller.{AnAction} or APIV2Controller.{AnAction}.

After Googling and Stackoverflowing about how to transfer, invoke or call another controller and action without redirection. Seems there is no good answer and good practise. Someone answer [.NET MVC Call method on different controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296680/net-mvc-call-method-on-different-controller/1296696#1296696) by simply creating new instance of the controller. Suddenly I got the idea how about to `reroute`!

**The question:**

Is it possible to `reroute` the the other controller and action from another action without redirection and how to do that?

Or a specific question, when user request `http://domain.com/API/{AnAction}` with `Version="2.0"`, how can I `reroute` from `APIController.Index` to `APIV2Controller.{AnAction}`?

I am not using IoC.

Comment: Seems there is no way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done via routing constraints. Firstly implement `IRouteConstraint`:

```
public class RequestParameterConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public string ParameterName { get; private set; }
    public string ParameterValue { get; private set; }

    public RequestParameterConstraint(string parameter, string value)
    {
        ParameterName = parameter;
        ParameterValue = value;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName,
        RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var value = httpContext.Request[ParameterName] ?? "";
        return value.Equals(ParameterValue);
    }
}
```

Then register routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Version10",
    "API/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "APIV1", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { header = new RequestParameterConstraint("Version", "1.0") }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    "Version20",
    "API/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "APIV2", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { header = new RequestParameterConstraint("Version", "2.0") }
    );
```

That's all. This will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

http://coderjournal.com/2010/09/simple-rest-api-versioning-using-mef-and-mvc/

This seems to do exactly what you want, but it takes a very different approach by using a completely different set of controllers, rather than rerouting to them.

Hope this helps.